# Strange HD Tune benchmark for Western Digital WD20SPZX (2.5" 2-TB hard disk)

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I am getting these strange looking HD Tune benchmark results on a Western Digital WD20SPZX 2.5" 2-TB hard disk.

The first picture is from the day I got it, and the others are on later dates as indicated.

Questions are:

1. Is this a bad disk?  Should I stop using it?
   I hope that was definite enough.  From here, I don't know enough about these disks to frame any precise question, but:
2. How should I understand the first (March 2022) picture, where the speed remains at a constant 200 MB/s.  I am sure this spinning disk is not that good.
3. How should I understand the remaining pictures (Mar and May 2023), where the speed is uneven but suddenly picks up at the very end, again to 200 MB/s.

I am told that I don't have enough reputation to embedded pictures.  So you'll have to click the links for them.  Sorry about that.  Thanks.

March 2022:

[image: March 2022]

March 2023:

[image: March 2023]

May 2023:

[image: May 2023]

ADDED LATER

See my own answer below for what happened to the benchmark when I

- filled the disk with zero's per solution in gronostag's answer and
- subsequently copied data to the disk

Question 1 above should now mean whether these successive benchmarks are normal for an SMR disk or indicate this particular one's going bad.  (I would think a CMR disk with deep valleys as on the final benchmark was in trouble.) Thanks.

Comment: What does the "Health" tab display?

Comment: @DavidPostill. The "Health" tab is a clean bill of health.  No yellow line, and no bad numbers. (Thanks for editing the post, to show pictures.)

Comment: I've edited the model in title and 1st paragraph to match your screenshots. (The model you've specified doesn't exist)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to WD website, WD20SPZX is a SMR drive. SMR stands for Shingled Magnetic Recording, a technology where pieces of data on drive platters overlap slightly like shingles. This makes producing high-capacity drives easier, at the cost of drives exhibiting all kinds of weird performance characteristics.

SMR drives usually return to normal characteristics after either overwriting with zeros, TRIM-ming or issuing secure erase command. All of these imply data loss.

What you're seeing is not unexpected for SMR drives. If you're not happy with that, you'll have to get a CMR drive. It may be difficult to find one at this capacity and form factor.

---

Regarding your questions from the comments.

With the shingled arrangement data can still be read randomly from the drive, but writing doesn't work that way: writing to any shingle will also destroy data in the shingles that overlap it. As a consequence if you want to overwrite any single byte, you have to read all bytes that follow it into memory first, then overwrite your byte and restore bytes that follow it from memory. To make the impact of this issue manageable the drive is divided into "zones". Shingles at the beginning and end of a zone don't overlap any other and aren't overlapped themselves. Thus to modify a byte, the drive only has to rewrite the rest of the zone, rather than the whole rest of the drive.

For some reasons (which I don't fully understand, so I won't try to explain them here) SMR drives also have a "Shingle Translation Layer" which is a SMR equivalent of a Flash Translation Layer (FTL) present in SSDs. Both do essentially the same thing: they let the drive actually store data in different places and order than the computer using the drive thinks it is. So when the computer thinks it's reading a large, continuous piece of data, blocks of that data can actually be scattered all around the drive - essentially fragmented, but OS isn't aware of it. On SSDs fragmentation is not an issue for the most part, but HDDs suffer from it significantly because drive heads have to be moved back and forth between spread apart pieces of data.

That explains what you're seeing: your SMR drive is probably fragmented internally, except for the outer part which probably saw less use.

> Instead of overwriting with zeros, could I format the drive and write new data? (If entering all zeros works, why shouldn't entering zeros and ones?)

A "quick" format doesn't overwrite most of the drive. It only creates a new empty filesystem which makes the rest of the drive appear unused (nb. this is why data recovery is sometimes possible after a format). Filesystems are just structured data and from drive's perspective creating one is no different than eg. writing a file to a drive.

A "full" format will do that + write zeroes to the drive, mostly achieving your goal.

Writing zeroes is special because the STL can recognize what you're doing and instead of mapping these addresses to some random on-disk location, it can mark them as zeroed. In a sense it "resets" that address in STL. TRIM achieves the same thing, but more explicitly. Note that TRIM support or special treatment of zeroes are not mandatory (although TRIM is at least standardized, although designed for a different purpose). Secure erase is a last resort: it has reasonably widespread support and it just makes sense to reset STL in the process.

> If (in spite of the strange looking benchmark) the read and write speeds in practical use are acceptable, I could just continue to my normal use pattern? (Or will that cause performance to become worse and worse?).

Nobody can tell, really. In my opinion SMR should be avoided unless you know that it will work well for your use case.

> My first graph (the constant 200 or 250 MB/s) is normal for SMR in its pristine or well-kept condition? It's amazing to me how this layering, or staggering, could give you that kind of speed. But I just want to make sure that 200 MB/s is not a sign of something else gone wrong, e.g. HD Tune not being able to measure SMR properly.

Here's a product brief for [that drive family](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-blue-hdd/product-brief-western-digital-wd-blue-mobile-sata-hdd.pdf). SMR models have nominal speed of 149-150 MB/s, compared to 147 MB/s for CMR drives. I suppose the results you got on day 1 are only reachable on an unused (or reset) drive because "clear" STL gives it an edge.

Comment: Thank you. I've followed up on your lead and read a bit about SMR. I have these further questions, and if you could expand your answer to cover them it would be really great.  1. Instead of overwriting with zeros, could I format the drive and write new data? (If entering all zeros works, why shouldn't entering zeros and ones?)  2. If (in spite of the strange looking benchmark) the read and write speeds in practical use are acceptable, I could just continue to my normal use pattern? (Or will that cause performance to become worse and worse?).

Comment: Also, here's a clarifying question.  My first graph (the constant 200 or 250 MB/s) is normal for SMR in its pristine or well-kept condition? It's amazing to me how this layering, or staggering, could give you that kind of speed. But I just want to make sure that 200 MB/s is not a sign of something else gone wrong, e.g. HD Tune not being able to measure SMR properly.

Comment: @cowpow I've updated the answer.

Comment: Quick format could work if the SMR drive supports TRIM, FWIW. Writing zeros actually will cause the sectors written to to be mapped to LBA addresses, so IOW as far as drive is concerned these are in use sectors. It will make the drive slower as when you write to same LBA address it will have to find another available band/zone.

Comment: This could also explain the 'flat line' in initial benchmark if it was ran on a 'virgin' drive. As none of the LBA addresses got mapped yet, the drive "knows" it's dealing with an empty sector and may return zeros without even accessing the platter. Similar to as how an SSD behaves when reading non mapped LBA addresses (RZAT).

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Some SMR drives - maybe manufactured by Seagate, I can't remember - regain their initial performance after filling with zeros. IIRC I've seen it reported on r/datahoarders

Comment: I believe you but it's counter intuitive unless you accomplish the zeroing by for example using built in secure erase. Of course things may be different IF a drive actually monitors what's being written, so it could then detect zeros en unmap LBA address written to. But AFAIK this is not happening yet, I may be wrong. But in essence what I am saying is, for the drive it does not matter if you write block of zeros or actual high entropy data, it will write the data and add sector to FTL (map to LBA).

Comment: A small addition with regards to fragmentation: Apart from file system level fragmentation on a lower level the bands or zones on a SMR drive can become fragmented too. To defrag that (some drives may do), drive needs plenty of idle time.

Comment: "For some reasons (which I don't fully understand, so I won't try to explain them here)" - it's because operating systems don't understand shingled drives, so they have to pretend like they are non-shingled drives. Hope that answers your question. I have read that there was some work on making Linux understand shingled drives, so you can get better and more predictable performance, but I don't think it's a thing yet.

Comment: @user253751 That doesn't explain why exactly STL is necessary. You're correct that disk-managed SMR is a useful thing, but that doesn't explain why STL is needed.

Comment: @gronostaj to make the shingled drive look like a non-shingled drive

Comment: @user253751 Let me rephrase the question: what is the advantage of making physical addresses independent from logical addresses? Shingles themselves don't make it necessary, at least not directly: addressing could still be uniform, just with drive's firmware taking care of zone-aware writing. I suppose avoiding in-place writes is an advantage in case of power loss, but I don't know if that's the sole reason.

Comment: @gronostaj "the drive's firmware taking care of zone-aware writing" is called an STL

Comment: @user253751 I don't think that's correct, at least not entirely. STL, as far as I understand, is the equivalent of FTL in SSDs. It's a mapping of logical addresses to physical addresses. The "translation" in the name is translation of addresses. The same concept is employed in SSDs to enable partial page writing and could be implemented in CMR HDDs if there was a reason for it.

Comment: @gronostaj yes, this is done so that writing is done in a zone-aware way. If you try to overwrite a sector the drive cannot overwrite it, but has to write the new sector at the end of a zone and then when you read it, remember to read the new sector instead of the old one. And when a zone has too much old data, move the still-good data somewhere else and erase the zone. This is extremely similar to the problems that flash memory drives have to deal with.

Comment: @user253751 That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This will perhaps be only partial answer. I think what we see is:

[image]

I am assuming this is a 'virgin' drive. What I mean by it is no data has been written yet and therefore the 'translator' is empty.

The 'translator' is a firmware directory that maps logical block addresses to a physical address. Sort of how the MFT maps files to clusters. Other parts of 'the translator' are the 'defect lists'.

[image]

So assume you read LBA 1000 from the virgin drive, then:

- the drive looks for this LBA in translator to determine which physical address is mapped to it
- finds there is none yet
- it returns a sector worth of zeros without ever reading the drive

As a result the benchmark does not show the typical increase in read time towards the end of the drive as it is not actually reading the drive. In fact, the only way to explain this sort of 'flat line' is by assuming that the drive is not doing actual reads.

To get that same graph again once the drive has been in use for some times, you'd need to TRIM the drive as it will again 'unmap' LBA addresses from physical addresses.

Writing zeros will not achieve the effect as writing zeros to an LBA will still map the LBA to a physical address. In fact after zero filling the entire drive, apart from some overprovisioned zones, all LBA addresses will be mapped to physical addressed.

In effect after both TRIM and writing zeros, we read zeros back once we read the drive. But after zeroing we read actual zeros from the platters, after 'trimming' the drive returns zero filled sectors without reading the drive in a similar fashion as most SSD's (assuming drive is RZAT after TRIM, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)).

Trimming should also have a positive effect on write speed, in fact that what trimming was designed for, as the drive will have less trouble allocating a zone to write new data to.

Note that not all SMR drives support TRIM.

With regards to for example,

[image]

we need to consider that even if we read a sector with a lower LBA address that would on a CMR drive be physically located in the more outer and faster tracks, an SMR drive can 'map' the lower range LBA address to another physical (and perhaps slower) part of the drive. And although the firmware may try to avoid 'fragmentation', theoretically LBA 101 - 200 could be somewhere entirely different than LBA 201 - 300 which could influence sequential reading (if we ignore read-ahead caching). IOW, a HD Tune benchmark for an SMR drive is much less predictable than one for a CMR drive. And so the question, "look at this benchmark, is my drive okay?" is harder to answer when dealing with an SMR rather than a CMR drive as there are simply more variables.

A frequently used SMR drive that does not support TRIM and that's not allowed idle time will slowly fall victim to entropy and reads and writes will become slower and a benchmark graph will get more erratic over time. The only thing between this and us is the fact the drive will try caching reads and writes. As long as the caching can keep up this may be hidden from us.

These SMART values look okay to me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. (1) The main lesson here for me seems to be that my pictures do not suggest a disk about to fail.  (2) "A frequently used SMR drive that does not support TRIM and that's now allowed idle time will..."  I believe you meant *not* instead of *now*. (3) How do I find out whether my particular model supports TRIM?

Comment: (1) - I see no indicators for failure at this point. (2) - thanks, I have corrected it. (3) - A tool like CrystalDiskInfo would list TRIM in features field.

Comment: This model does have TRIM (HD Tune, Info tab). But since TRIM happens to unused space (somewhere in this now long post), and I plan to keep the disk mostly filled, I expect no miracles. The erratic benchmark does not yet translate to erratic experience. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This answer supplements that of gronostaj in that it reports on an implementation of the solution there suggested, i.e.

> SMR drives usually return to normal characteristics after either overwriting with zeros, TRIM-ming or issuing secure erase command

What I did was to use a Windows app called [Diskwipe](https://www.diskwipe.org/).

The "wiping" process was made of "formatting" (which took hours) and separately "secure erasing" (again hours so the combined processes must have taken some 15 to 20 hours for this 2 TB disk though I'd gone to sleep when it completed).  In the picture below I believe 09:40:49 of elapsed time is just for the "secure erasing" phase.

[image]

And here's the result.

May 2023 #2:

[image]

Observations.

1. I am happy that a "return to normal characteristics" didn't mean the artificial constant 200 MB/s of March 2022.
2. Happy that the deep valleys of March 2023 and May 2023 are gone.
3. Cannot explain to myself the spike toward 125 MB/s at the end.  (It does not seem to be the same thing as the spikes on previous dates.  The segment and the speed are different.)

The results as above were good (thanks again to gronostaj), but I cannot say they make me happy with this SMR drive.  I don't want to have to do this periodically.

The disk was not installed in any computer, but was a backup disk.  I must have "used" it less than 30 times (plug in, back something up, plug out).  See below for usage.  Much of the Power On Hours Count is testing for bad sector when I got the thing and this wiping.

[image]

Maybe I'll fill this disk with some things once (so there has been no re-write after wipe) and benchmark again. If the result is interesting, will amend this answer with it.

ADDED LATER

Here's the benchmark after I copied about 800 GB of stuff to the affected disk, consisting of small (text at a few KB) and large (disk images at up to 20 GB).

May 2023 #3:

[image]

You see that the disk has already become "bad."  The first 100 GB segment, which is very "bad" with deep valleys, is where the data include many small files.  The latter segments are most large files (disk images, virtual drives).

This is turning into another question.  Namely:

4. Is this a bad disk given the new results, or are they expected results on an SMR drive?

I don't know how to manage this per this site rules, whether to amend the existing question or to post a new one.

Comment: *I don't want to have to do this periodically* You don't have to and shouldn't do it, at all, just use it like you would any other drive. The automatic TRIM any modern OS routinely does should be enough as a maintenance.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Does TRIM work if I plug in the drive only when copying to or from it?  Or does it need plugged-in idle time?

Comment: I think the SMR will consider zeros just data and as such will not help. TRIM will unmap LBA addresses. As result *reads* get quicker IF SMR drive handles them anything like most SSD's: Say if I read LBA 1000 after that sector was part of TRIM packet, drive can deliver zeros without even even reading the sector.

Comment: @ChanganAuto TRIM will only affect unused disk space, and only if the drive acually implements it. Users will naturally be concerned about the performance when accessing used disk space which isn't TRIM-med and will suffer from internal fragmentation. Joep van Steen suggested in the comment on my answer that SMR drives may defragment while plugged in for long periods of time, but that's not how you would normally be using an external drive and it will imply huge write amplification. (To be clear, I mean internal fragmentation below the shingle translation layer, not logical fragmentation)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't referring to logical fragmentation either. Write amplification is something you'd want to avoid on SSD's but I don't see a fundamental objection for SMR drives. Idle time does not perse mean hours, a few minutes of inactivity may be all that's needed to trigger background tasks. Firmware gets more and more complex and advanced with each generation of drives and some may already distinguish between hot and cold data and place accordingly. Studies on defragmentation on this level were already conducted in 2014, good chance it may already have been implemented.

Comment: With regards to TRIM: TRIM is a *command*, a means for an OS or utility to inform the drive about unused space. So trimming happens while you're using the drive, deleted files, after you format a drive etc.. LBA addresses which it concerns are 'unmapped', SCSI calls trimming 'unmap' even. Then during idle time firmware of an SSD will consolidate erase blocks and erase them so they're ready for use. An SMR drive may put discarded zones to use to reorganize existing data, move cold data to slower parts of the drive for example.